# Can we use ceedling with Bazel?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, bazel, bazel-rules, ceedling

I'm working on unit tests for a c embedded project with Bazel, first I tested the code with Ceedling (Unity and cmock) and It worked. And now, I'm trying to merge to Bazel but I did not find any document about using ceedling with Bazel.

Comment: You might try google/pigweed/pw_unit_test instead it's effectively a googletest port for embedded systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a quick research and it looks like there is no ceedling support for Bazel. You could write some custom rules for stuff you have mentioned, but I guess, that rewriting to Bazel rules will be much easier and maintainable

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to know how to mock test using Bazel this is my problem write now, because Ceedling uses Unity and Cmock, for unity it's not a problem I can link my Bazel project to this library, but for for cmock it's complicated. I read some things about gmock  in googleTest, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I see problem here: gmock does not requires any code generation: it is a pure C++ library. Cmock (probably) generate code using some external scripts, you can try to use a https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genrule to generate files using cmock

Comment: And last question, do you know what's better to use for mocking c embedded gmock in google test or cmocka (not cmock) with Bazel?